# How to select distinct rows from groupby object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop rows from a groupby object based on a condition:

```
Group    value
  A        0
  A       20
  A       25
  B        5
  C        6
  C       17
```

With a dataframe, if I wanted to drop anything with a value less than 10, I could just call `df[df['value']>=10]`. I can't seem to find a way to do something similar with a groupby object to get.

```
 Group    value
  A       20
  A       25
  C       17
```

Comment: This would just select unique rows, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. No?

Comment: How can you group by 'Group' and still have two 'A' rows? I believe you want to do indexing, not groupby.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration).
If want to return the rows concerning groups with value sum is larger than or equal 10:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('Group')

In [12]: g.filter(lambda x: x.value.sum() >= 10)
Out[12]: 
  Group  value
0     A      0
1     A     20
2     A     25
4     C      6
5     C     17

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

*You need to provide a function which acts on each subDataFrame and returns a boolean result, an example of a subDataFrames is `df[df['Group'] == 'A']`.*

Comment: I tried filter and it seems like it only allows you to select by group, not within group.

Comment: @Luke yes, that's what it does! Why not just do this outside the groupby?

Answer (score 1):

Either I don't understand your intention, or the solution is trivial:

```
group = "A A A B C C".split()
value = [0,20,25,5,6,17]
df = DataFrame(zip(group, value), columns='group value'.split())
df

     group   value
0    A       0
1    A       20
2    A       25
3    B       5
4    C       6
5    C       17

g = df.groupby('group')
g.sum()[(g.sum() >=10)['value']]

     value
group   
A    45
C    23
```

I guess you are assuming that you can select stuff within the groupby object. As far as I know, you can't. But you can do that in the resulting object, **after** you apply your aggregation function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am indeed looking for within group selection before applying an aggregation function. It would be a nice feature to have!

Comment: Why? If you want to select before aggregating, then just select `df[df['value']>=10]` before aggregating `df.groupby('Group')`.